# serve compressed file with no file extension with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, webpagetest

I have a website chat plugin script that I've made a local copy of, and uploaded to our website: `www.example.com/js/default`.

webpagetest.org reports this file is uncompressed.

In .htaccess, we have:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
```

Is this not enough to compress `www.example.com/js/default` ?

If not, what do we need to add to `.htaccess`? Thanks.

Comment: Check response headers using command line `curl` or browser's developer tool to see what is the `Content-Type`

Comment: I ended up renaming `default` to `default.js` which solved the problem, and the chat software still worked, but others may have this question.